# Is std::forward() always used in a template function?

Tags: c++, perfect-forwarding, forwarding-reference

Can anyone give me a non-template function definition showing an explicit call to std::forward()?

I guess the parameter to forward() is always(?) a universal reference. A universal reference could be declared "auto" like

```
auto&& var2=var1;
```

With this var2, could a non-template function do:

```
return make_shared<Person>(forward(var2)); //is this meaningless/useless in a non-template function?
```

Comment: Can we give you a function? Yes. Is there any reason to write such a function? No.

Comment: @Mooing Duck: I am under the impression "a non-template function definition showing an explicit call to std::forward()" is unlikely to be useful, even if I were to write such a function.